# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at VueComponent.eval

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, api

Не могу понять почему возникает ошибка.

```
created: function(){
        this.$http.get('wp/v2/pages').then(response => {
          for (let page in response.data){
              this.pages.push(response.data[page]);                  
          }
```

Comment: this.pages - у Вас ссылка this это не объект Vue (как Вы предполагаете), данный this ссылается на ф-ию get объекта $http, в которой Вы находитесь. В этой ф-ии нет pages, а значит this.pages будет равен undefined (у которого нет метода push).

Comment: Вроде объявлял заранее
`export default {
    name: 'App',
    props: {
        msg: String,
        pages: []
    },`

Comment: Как вариант - сделать до вызова this.$http.get(...) константу const then = this. И обращаться then.pages.push(response.data[page]);

Comment: export default это Вы в компоненте объявили, в компоненте оно и осталось. Но this.pages.push - здесь Вы обращаетесь не к компоненту.

Answer (score 0):

Надо было перенести значения из props в data.

```
data: function () {
      return {
        lists: []
      }
  }
```

В функции были пропущены скобки

```
created:function () {
            this.$http.get('wp/v2/pages').then(**(**response**)** => {
             for (let list in response.data) {
                this.lists.push(response.data[list]);
                }
```